# How can I get a batch of frames from consumers.py?

Tags: javascript, django, websocket, computer-vision, django-channels

I am working on a computer vision project involving object detection and real-time frame streaming using OpenCV and Django. To accomplish this, I am utilizing Django channels. However, I have encountered a new challenge where I need to perform video classification. This requires sending a batch of frames to the model. Can anyone provide any guidance on how to approach this issue?

I added a button on the front end. What I expected was to obtain a single timestamp from the backend consumers.py. I got the timestamp of the start frame until the timestamp of the frame where the button was clicked.

[image: Timestamp obtained upon single click]

In the consumers.py file, I'm utilizing the OpenCV library to iterate through the frames and transmit that data to the WebSocket client. Here is an example of the code (I have also provided the comments for better understanding).

```
# Import the 'cv2' module, which is the OpenCV library for computer vision tasks.
import cv2

# Import the 'json' module for working with JSON data.
import json

# Import the 'asyncio' module for asynchronous programming support.
import asyncio

# Import the 'datetime' module for working with date and time.
import datetime

# Import the 'numpy' module for numerical and array operations.
import numpy as np

# Import a custom function 'serialize_frame' from the 'processing' module in the current application.
from .processing import serialize_frame

# Import the 'AsyncWebsocketConsumer' class from Django's 'channels.generic.websocket' module.
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

# Define a custom WebSocket consumer class named VideoConsumer that handles WebSocket communication.
class VideoConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    # Define the 'connect' method for WebSocket connection handling.

    # This method is executed when a WebSocket connection is established.
    async def connect(self):
        # Accept the WebSocket connection.
        await self.accept()

        # Retrieve the video file path from the URL route parameters.
        video_file_path = self.scope['url_route']['kwargs']['video_path']

        # Send processed frames using the video file path.
        await self.send_processed_frames(video_file_path)

    # Define the 'send_frame' method for sending video frame data and match data to the WebSocket client.

    # This method takes 'frame_data' and 'match_data' as parameters and sends them as JSON to the WebSocket client.
    async def send_frame(self, frame_data, timestamp_str):
        # Convert the frame data and match data into a JSON format and send it to the client.
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps({
            'frame_data': frame_data,
            'timestamp': timestamp_str
        }))

    # Define the 'send_processed_frames' method for processing and sending video frames and match data.
    # This method takes 'video_file_path' as a parameter and processes video frames and related data.
    async def send_processed_frames(self, video_file_path):
        # Initialize data structures and variables.
        # A dictionary for actions

        try:
            cap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_file_path)
            
            # Start iterating over the frames
            while True:

                ret, frame = cap.read()

                #  Get the timestamp of the frame on which the prediction is being performed
                timestamp = cap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_MSEC)
                timestamp = datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=timestamp)

                timestamp_str = str(timestamp).split('.', 2)[0]

                # Encode the frames to base64 to send to the web
                frame_data = serialize_frame(frame)  # Implement the serialization function

                # Send the frame data and match data to the WebSocket client.
                await self.send_frame(frame_data, timestamp_str)
                # Adjust the frame rate as needed (e.g., 30 frames per second).
                await asyncio.sleep(0.033)


                # Release the video capture object.
            cap.release()
        except Exception as e:
            # In case of an error, send an error message to the WebSocket client.
            await self.send(text_data=f"Error: {str(e)}")

    async def receive(self, text_data):

        # Handle messages from WebSocket
        message = json.loads(text_data)

        print(message)
```

I have specified the route in routing.py.

```
# Import necessary modules for URL routing in Django.
from django.urls import re_path

# Import the 'VideoConsumer' class from the 'consumers' module of the current application.
from . import consumers

# Define WebSocket URL patterns for the application.

# Create a WebSocket URL pattern that captures the 'video_path' parameter from the URL.
# It routes WebSocket requests to the 'VideoConsumer' class using the 'as_asgi()' method.
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'ws/video/(?P<video_path>[\w\W]+)/$', consumers.VideoConsumer.as_asgi())
]
```

I then send the data from the backend to the front end.

```
{% extends 'main.html' %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container text-center">
    <h1>Processing Video</h1>
    <br>

    <!-- <img class="rounded" id="liveImage" width="800" height="600"> -->
    <div class="liveImage">
        <div class="text-secondary text-center" role="status">
        </div>
        <img class="rounded" id="liveImage">
    </div>  
    <hr>
    
    <h5>To classify the cover type, specify the start duration to clip the video</h5>
    <div class="d-grid gap-2">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="sendTimestampButton" type="button">Button</button>
    </div>
</div>

<br>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/js/all.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
        let videoPath = "{{ video_path }}";  // Use the video path from your Django template
        let liveImage = document.getElementById("liveImage");

        // Establish a WebSocket connection to your server
        let wsProtocol = window.location.protocol === "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
        let wsURL = `${wsProtocol}://${window.location.host}/ws/video/${videoPath}/`;
        let socket = new WebSocket(wsURL);

        // document.getElementById('sendTimestampButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
        //     // Send a message to the backend to request the timestamp
        //     socket.send(JSON.stringify({'request_timestamp': true}));
        //     console.log('TimeStamp: ');
        // });

        socket.onopen = function (event) {
            console.log('Websocket Connection established')
        }
        
        socket.onmessage = function (event) {
            let data = JSON.parse(event.data);

            document.getElementById('sendTimestampButton').addEventListener('click', function () {
            //     // Send a message to the backend to request the timestamp
                socket.send(JSON.stringify({'timestamp': data.timestamp}));
                console.log('Timestamp: ', data.timestamp);
            });

                
                liveImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data.frame_data;
            } 

        socket.onclose = function (event) {
            console.log("WebSocket connection closed.");
        };

        socket.onerror = function (error) {
            console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
        };
    });    
</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

To look at the complete code, check the repo: https://github.com/ShahZebYousafzai/Django-Real-Time-Inference-on-video

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this! I defined an initial variable at the beginning of the `VideoConsumer` Class in the consumers.py. In the while loop, I described this variable as a class variable and stored the current timestamp of the frame. In veiws.py, I make a function class that sends a JSON response. I am getting the timestamp and sending it as a JSON response in that function. In the front end, I use AJAX to get the response. Whenever I click the button, I get a timestamp of the frame.